Connecting Discord and Telegram Accounts
So I am currently working on a way to link your discord user ID and telegram user ID into my mongoDB, in python. I currently have it so in discord I create a button that the user can click on and get an OAUTH link for Telegram for them to sign in. I have that working locally with ngrok and it's working fine.
The issue I'm having is once I connect with the login widget in Telegram, it displays my IP to whoever is connecting to the ngrok site, and that's not what I want. Is there a way to avoid it exposing my IP to anyone who clicks the link? If not, is there a better way to have discord send a login request to telegram so my DB can store the userID from telegram into it?
